# AS3 Constructors - what is the point?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, actionscript

You can declare variables outside of the constructor in a class, so what is the point of a constructor in AS3?

Example:

```
 package {
    public class traceText {
        var i:String = "Hello!";
        public function traceText() {
        }
        public function sayHello() {
            trace(i);
        }
    }
}

import traceText;
j = new traceText;
j.sayHello();
```

I do know that you cannot call functions, however what is the purpose of the constructor when the code in the class is executed? Why not allow functions and make it simpler?

I apologize if I'm being ignorant, I'm learning as3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example there is no use for a constructor. In fact if you left it out the compiler would have gone ahead and added the exact same thing for you.

The objective of a constructor is to give the class designers a location to allocate resources.

Also you can define parameters in a constructor to force the class consumers to provide arguments to the constructor without which the class would not function. That is not the case in your simple class and therefore the constructor is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

The [constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) is part the [**object oriented programming**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) paradigm and is independent from AS3:

> In object-oriented programming, a
>   constructor in a class is a special type of
>   subroutine called at the creation of
>   an object. It prepares the new object
>   for use, often accepting parameters
>   which the constructor uses to set any
>   member variables required when the
>   object is first created. [more...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the obviousness of the the answer to your question, I have a feeling that I may have misinterpreted it. So please let me know if this is the case.

The constructor contains code that will be run as soon as an instance of your class is created.

A good example of this would be putting the following into a constructor:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
```

So that all new instances of your class will "come equipped" with this event listener applied.

If you don't need to make use of the constructor, then you don't need to manually created like in your example; it will be automatically created when you compile the application.

Comment: Wait, when you create a new instance of a class is created, not all code is executed? If that is the code, then why would 'var i:String = "Hello!";' work?

Comment: I was reluctant to answer his question because the question seemed to straight forward. I think gladoscc perhaps  doesn't understand the use of classes as opposed to the timeline, but then again I could be wrong.

Comment: Good practice is to always create the constructor even if you leave it empty. If the compiler can not find a constructor one will be generated automatically. Another good practice is to scope your class vars public var i:String = "Hello!"; In your case I would scope it as private since there is a function "sayHello()" that is used to access it.